# Themeroller bootstrap version difference?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes, themeroller

I want to customize my bootstrap colors with [themeroller](http://www.bootstrapthemeroller.com/twitter-bootstrap-themeroller.html#@headingsFontWeight=bold&@navbarBackground=#0b76f2&)

But themeroller theme also seems to have different button styles. I want to keep the normal bootstrap style but just change the colors. Can it be possible themeroller uses a other bootstrap version then 3?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support version 3 as of now. If you want to go for version 2 itself, then you could do this via using Advanced settings tab and inside change the button settings alone.

AND FYI, Twitter is stopping the support for version 2.3.2 customization so its a possibility that custom downloads with themeroller will also stop